# Sort product collection by Latitude and Longitude

Tags: magento2, product-collection, sorting

I need to sort product collection by latitude and longitude in product listing and search page.

**Explanation:**

I have two product attributes **Latitude** and **Longitude**. All product has single Latitude and Longitude. Now on product listing page we need to sort product collection by current latitude and longitude.

Suppose my current location latitude is **36.778259** and longitude is **-119.417931**, In product listing page All product with latitude **36.778259** and longitude **-119.417931** has to display first in list page and other near by latitude and longitude products should display respectively and so on. I guess we need to use Google Map API for doing it but not sure how do I do it.

Please provide me some solutions. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Releated to Google Map API, you can use as a reference this module: https://github.com/ClaudiuCreanga/magento2-store-locator-stockists-extension

Comment: Yes, But how can we sort product collection by latitude and longitude? What would be the collection query to achieve  that?